# How to document ROS2 Python package source code?

Tags: ros2, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the current best practice to document the source code of a ROS2 (Bouncy, `colcon` build) Python package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300961/how-to-document-ros2-python-package-source-code?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/300963/how-to-document-ros2-c-package-source-code/?answer=301067#post-id-301067).

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-08-21**:
In addition to my comments in the referenced answer: The sphinx extensions should be usable without limitations, right? Means the non-default docstring styles (NumPy, Google) should be supported via `napoleon`. Autogeneration via `sphinx-apidoc` should be usable as well. Right?

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-08-21**:
Any documentation tool can be used without limitations in your package.